# Move Laravel Jetstream profile photo component to different View

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I am building a web app using Laravel Jetstream: i have moved the [Profile Information (1st Section)] (https://jetstream.laravel.com/3.x/features/profile-management.html) Section of User Profile where user can upload profile photo to a different view by moving

```
@if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::canUpdateProfileInformation())
  @livewire('profile.update-profile-information-form')  
  <x-section-border />
@endif
```

to my custom view.

Everything works but I am unable to figure out redirect! Whenever i update profile photo and save it redirects back to Profile View rather than my custom view

However, when i update email or name, it stays at my custom View

question: where can i update redirect so it redirects to my custom view?

I checked the `\app\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation.php` as stated in the documentation but it doesn't have any redirects.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out: u need to update `\vendor\Laravel\jetstream\src\Http\Livewire\UpdateProfileInformationForm.php`

```
public function updateProfileInformation(UpdatesUserProfileInformation $updater)
{
    $this->resetErrorBag();

    $updater->update(
        Auth::user(),
        $this->photo
            ? array_merge($this->state, ['photo' => $this->photo])
            : $this->state
    );

    if (isset($this->photo)) {
        return redirect()->route('basicinfo');
    }

    $this->emit('saved');

    $this->emit('refresh-navigation-menu');
}
```

Comment: You should never update something in the /vendor directory, as it's managed by composer and will be overwritten when updating your composer dependencies.